# jquery display a div if a text is upto a particular length

Tags: jquery, text, long-integer

please I need help. I have long article to display and the text is up to 400 characters. But I want to display an ads inside the article if when the characters are up to 200.

Here is my code:

`<div class="article" id="showAds"> Long text. ...</div>`

Here's the ads to display:
`<div class="ads"></div>`

Comment: Why don't you write some Javascript that grabs the innerHTML and checks its length?

Comment: Please can you give me an example? Am new to programming

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the length of the stuff in the `DIV` like so:

```
 var x=document.getElementById("DivOfInterest").innerHTML.length;
```

Based on the value of `x` you can choose to take whatever action you'd like.